# JQuery Uncaught TypeError: $(...).resizable is not a function

Tags: jquery, resizable

I'm trying to use this example:

"Simple example that demonstrates how to create slidable two-pane layouts using FlexBox and the resizable plug-in. Note that Flexbox is not required, but used here to keep the layout simple."

https://codepen.io/rstrahl/pen/eJZQej

However, it does not work for me:

```js
$(".panel-left").resizable({
        handleSelector: ".splitter",
        resizeHeight: false
    });
    $(".panel-top").resizable({
        handleSelector: ".splitter-horizontal",
        resizeWidth: false
    });
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.page-container {
  margin: 20px;
}


/* horizontal panel*/

.panel-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  /* avoid browser level touch actions */
  xtouch-action: none;
}

.panel-left {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  /* only manually resize */
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 150px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #838383;
  color: white;
}

.splitter {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 18px;  
  background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/assets/vsizegrip.png) center center no-repeat #535353;
  min-height: 200px;
  cursor: col-resize;  
}

.panel-right {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  /* resizable */
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  background: #eee;
}


/* vertical panel */

.panel-container-vertical {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-top {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  /* only manually resize */
  padding: 10px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #838383;
  color: white;
}

.splitter-horizontal {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 18px;
  background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/assets/hsizegrip.png) center center no-repeat #535353;
  cursor: row-resize;
}

.panel-bottom {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  /* resizable */
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: #eee;
}

label {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 30px 0 10px;
}

pre {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Split Panels - jquery-resizable</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../src/jquery-resizable.js"></script>

</head>
<body style="">
    <div class="page-container">

        <h1>
           jquery-resizable - A simple splitter panel
        </h1>
        <hr />

        <p>
            Simple example that demonstrates how to create slidable two-pane layouts <a href="http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox">using FlexBox</a> and the resizable plug-in.
            Note that Flexbox is not required, but used here to keep the layout simple.
        </p>

        <label>Horizontal Splitter Panes:</label>

        <div class="panel-container">

            <div class="panel-left">
                left panel
            </div>

            <div class="splitter">
            </div>

            <div class="panel-right">
                right panel
            </div>
        </div>

        <label>Vertical Splitter Panes:</label>
        <div class="panel-container-vertical">

            <div class="panel-top">
                top panel
            </div>

            <div class="splitter-horizontal">
            </div>

            <div class="panel-bottom">
                bottom panel
            </div>
        </div>



        <hr />

        <p>
            This example creates two resizables for the horizontal and vertical splitter panes:
        </p>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Can someone correct my code?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply correct script address to `<script src="https://rawgit.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/src/jquery-resizable.js"></script>`

```js
 $(".panel-left").resizable({
   handleSelector: ".splitter",
   resizeHeight: false
 });

 $(".panel-top").resizable({
   handleSelector: ".splitter-horizontal",
   resizeWidth: false
 });
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.page-container {
  margin: 20px;
}


/* horizontal panel*/

.panel-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  /* avoid browser level touch actions */
  xtouch-action: none;
}

.panel-left {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  /* only manually resize */
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 150px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #838383;
  color: white;
}

.splitter {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 18px;  
  background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/assets/vsizegrip.png) center center no-repeat #535353;
  min-height: 200px;
  cursor: col-resize;  
}

.panel-right {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  /* resizable */
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  background: #eee;
}


/* vertical panel */

.panel-container-vertical {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-top {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  /* only manually resize */
  padding: 10px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #838383;
  color: white;
}

.splitter-horizontal {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 18px;
  background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/assets/hsizegrip.png) center center no-repeat #535353;
  cursor: row-resize;
}

.panel-bottom {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  /* resizable */
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: #eee;
}

label {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 30px 0 10px;
}

pre {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Split Panels - jquery-resizable</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/src/jquery-resizable.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="">
        <div class="page-container">

            <h1>
               jquery-resizable - A simple splitter panel
            </h1>
            <hr />

            <p>
                Simple example that demonstrates how to create slidable two-pane layouts <a href="http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox">using FlexBox</a> and the resizable plug-in.
                Note that Flexbox is not required, but used here to keep the layout simple.
            </p>

            <label>Horizontal Splitter Panes:</label>

            <div class="panel-container">

                <div class="panel-left">
                    left panel
                </div>

                <div class="splitter">
                </div>

                <div class="panel-right">
                    right panel
                </div>
            </div>

            <label>Vertical Splitter Panes:</label>
            <div class="panel-container-vertical">

                <div class="panel-top">
                    top panel
                </div>

                <div class="splitter-horizontal">
                </div>

                <div class="panel-bottom">
                    bottom panel
                </div>
            </div>



            <hr />

            <p>
                This example creates two resizables for the horizontal and vertical splitter panes:
            </p>

        </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```